# android AdMob unit id

Tags: android, admob

I want to show Google AdMob interstitial ads in my app.
The documentation tells:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
```

What is `MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID` here?

In AdMob developer console I only can see "Publisher ID". Is Publisher ID the same as `MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is either your PublisherID or your MediationId (if you are using mediation).